# Plot not showing in python

Tags: python, graph, show

Looking at some code I grabbed from https://www.quantopian.com/posts/python-black-and-scholes-pde-finite-difference-method - Only thing is I'm not sure why the graph isn't showing up. I'm using Canopy.  Code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib as plt

T = 1  #Time to Expiry in Years
E = 100  #Strike
r = .05  #Risk Free Rate
SIGMA = .20  #Volatility
Type = True   #Type of Option True=Call False=Put
NAS = 40  #Number of Asset Steps - Higher is more accurate, but more time consuming

ds = 2 * E / NAS  #Asset Value Step Size
dt = (0.9/NAS/NAS/SIGMA/SIGMA)  #Time Step Size
NTS = int(T / dt) + 1  #Number of 

value_matrix = np.zeros((int(NAS+1), int(NTS)))
asset_price = np.arange(NAS*ds,-1,-ds)
value_matrix[:,-1]= np.maximum(asset_price - E,0)

for x in range(1,NTS):
    value_matrix[-1,-x-1] = value_matrix[-1,-x]* math.exp(-r*dt)
for x in range(1,int(NTS)):
    for y in range(1,int(NAS)):
        #Evaluate Option Greeks
        Delta = (value_matrix[y-1,-x] - value_matrix[y+1,-x]) / 2 / ds
        value_matrix[y+1,-x]
        Gamma = (value_matrix[y-1,-x] - (2 * value_matrix[y,-x]) + value_matrix[y+1,-x]) / ds / ds
        Theta = (-.5 * SIGMA**2 * asset_price[y]**2 * Gamma) - (r * asset_price[y] * Delta) + (r * value_matrix[y,-x])
        value_matrix[y,-x-1] = value_matrix[y,-x] - Theta * dt
        value_matrix[0,-x-1] = 2 * value_matrix[1,-x-1] - value_matrix[2,-x-1]
value_df = pd.DataFrame(value_matrix)
value_df = value_df.set_index(asset_price)
print(value_df[0])

plot_df = value_df.sort_index(ascending=True)
plot_df[0].plot()
plot_df[NTS-1].plot()
```

Comment: works for me in ipython. maybe tried adding a `plt.show()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have imported `matplotlib` itself as `plt`. This is not commonly done. Instead you want to import `matplotlib.pyplot`. This then allows you to do all the conventional plotting in `matplotlib` such as `plt.plot()` etc., in addition to showing any figures that have been generated using `pandas` plotting functionality which is what seems to be being used in the question

The solution to your problem is to add `plt.show()` at the end of your code using the correct module imports at the top of the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the rest of your code

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

When importing matplotlib in python you want to use the pyplot submodule. So you're going to want to change your import statement to

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

and then to view what is plotted you have to add

`plt.show()`

to the bottom of your code

Comment: If I do that I get an error - 'module' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: @undergrad Your import is also wrong... replace it with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1):

```
%matplotlib inline
```

If you're using jupyter notebook, you need to add the code above.

Comment: I'm not using iPython

Comment: Missed the Canopy part. My apologies.